# Accessing device configuration space - win kernel PCI device

Tags: windows, kernel, device-driver, wdk, pci

I'm writing method to get pci device, given vendor id, device id programmatically  (just like pci_get_device from Linux kernel).

For that I need to get device object configuration. I read from here for the same: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558707(v=vs.85).aspx

Now to test this, I made fake driver - service installation framework, which will install my I/O device driver and in that from DriverEntry I can test this PCI functionality.

But OS crashes with irql_not_less_or_equal, at

```
irp = IoBuildSynchronousFsdRequest(IRP_MJ_PNP,
                                       targetObject,
                                       NULL,
                                       0,
                                       NULL,
                                       &event,
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> &ioStatusBlock);
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with that, (I'm calling this from Driver Entry, and passing current installing driver's deviceObject.)

Comment: This I should be using from my "PCI device stack" driver e.g. PCI Function Driver ... and use pdo of that ... mine was NULL ... I thought it can generate from bus#, function #, device #. .. but I was wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a valid PDO in `DriverEntry()`. `DriverEntry` roughly corresponds to `main()` in user space application and is called first thing after driver load into memory. `DriverEntry` main purpose is to register the driver with the OS and its code is independent of actual device(s). You can have a PDO only after the OS has called your initialization callback (after it has recognized your device) - and the callback will be called after DriverEntry completion (actually, the callback should be provided to the OS as part of the driver registration inside the `DriverEntry()`).